# Add Values of Pandas Series with MultiIndex to Values of A Single Level Index Series

Tags: python, pandas

Given a pandas `Series` with simple index

```
import pandas as pd
simple_index_series = pd.Series([1,2,3], index=['a', 'b', 'c'])

a    1
b    2
c    3
```

And a Series with a MultiIndex

```
multi_index_series = pd.Series(
  0, 
  index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['foo', 'bar'], ['c', 'b', 'a']])
)

foo  c    0
     b    0
     a    0
bar  c    0
     b    0
     a    0
```

**How can the values of the single level index Series be numerically added to the values of the second Series based on matching up the the second level index?**

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you need to use the `level` parameter of [`add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html) :

> `Series.add`(other, level=None, fill_value=None, axis=0)
> *Addition of series and other, element-wise (binary operator add).*
>
> level : int or name
> **Broadcast across a level, matching Index values on the passed MultiIndex level**.
>
> *Source* : [[docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html)]

```py
# multi_index_series.index.get_level_values(1)
# Index(['c', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a'], dtype='object')

out = multi_index_series.add(simple_index_series, level=1)
```

---

​
Output :

```py
print(out)
    ​
foo  c    3
     b    2
     a    1
bar  c    3
     b    2
     a    1
dtype: int64
```